# Space following RTL word in LTR paragrap

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

When inserting RTL word in LTR paragraph (in Outlook 365, in which the typed emails seem to be basically a Word documetn), the space typed *after* the RTL (e.g. Hebrew) word will appear as a RTL space, i.e. to the left of the Hebrew word. (If a punctuation is entered immediately after the RTL word, it behaves as a LTR character, but spaces will always behave as RTL, even if I change the keyboard back to (e.g.) English before typing the space.

My sentence will therefore look like this:

"Hi, my name is  שלוםand I feel fine."

Instead of: Hi, my name is שלום and I feel fine."

(Changing the paragraph direction (in the ribbon) doesn't relate to this, as that determines the direction of the **paragraph** as a whole. Nor is this a problem of jumbled sentences, rather the *positioning* of the space.)

Comment: Is this the same behavior in Word?